# How do I access a certain field of 'object' without casting it to one type when it can be several types?

Tags: c#, object, casting, type-conversion

I have an object that can be assigned different classes, all of which have a `Position` field which I need to access regardless of the object's type. Visual Studio won't let me compile `var pos = myObject.Position` because `object` doesn't have a `Position` field. And I can't cast to `MyClass`, because there can be several other classes assigned to that variable.

How do I access the `Position` field without casting to one type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option would be to make all of your classes implement a common interface, and then use that interface to access the properties.

However, if these are classes outside of your control, there are other options.  You could use Reflection to access the field/property (via [Type.GetField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield.aspx) and [FieldInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx), etc), though this is slow at runtime.

If you're using C# 4 or later, you can use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic theObject = yourObject;
Point position = theObject.Position;
```

This will use dynamic (runtime) binding to find the `Position` property or field on your type.

Comment: Dynamic solved my problems :) I just had to add `using Microsoft.CSharp` to make it work.

Comment: Although I now realized using a `dynamic` forbids editing the code in scope of its use while debugging which is a huge inconvenience :( I'll try interfaces to avoid that.

Comment: @user1306322 Edit and continue doesn't work with dynamic - which is why I had specified that using a common interface is the best approach (my first sentence) - but the approach works fine.

Answer (score 1):

All of those different classes which have a `Position` field should either inherit that field from a common base class, or get it (it would have to be a property then) from a common interface.

The interface solution might look like this:

```
interface IHasPosition
{
  int Position { get; }
}
```

then all of the classes shall say `: IHasPosition`, and your `myObject` variable should be declared of type `IHasPosition` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Once option is to make all of the different classes inherit from a class which defines `Position` then when you get the object refer to it by the parent classes type and you can access the properties that are defined there without knowing the specific type.

Keep in mind if they don't have much common functionality this may not be a very good approach.

Comment: That would be difficult I think, they already have their own parent classes.

Comment: @user1306322 then I would recommend using Reed's approach.